# GcmListenerService: Received message with unknown type: 0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I keep on getting this message "GcmListenerService: Received message with unknown type: 0" from my android monitor whenever I try pushing a GCM to my android client. Does anyone know what it means or what I'm doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure I got the manifest and all right since yesterday I was able to get a message. But now I just get this.

Any info on what this means?